# Deep Linking not working when app is in background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, deep-linking, openurl

I am using following method to implement deep linking.

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation
```

When app is in background this method is not calling when I came from browser?. 
I have added all required procedures to implement deep linking.
How to solve this ?

Comment: Try implementing this one instead `application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:`

Comment: Tried but that method not calling.What should I do to get called that method ?

Comment: Here's a good tutorial, covering both iOS and backend parts of it.
https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/universal-links-in-ios-79c4ee038272

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                 restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    guard let dynamicLinks = FIRDynamicLinks.dynamicLinks() else {

        return false
    }

    let handled = dynamicLinks.handleUniversalLink(userActivity.webpageURL!) { (dynamiclink, error) in
        print(error as Any)
    }


    return handled
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#define App_Scheme   @"yourbundleappschme"

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation 
{
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:App_Scheme])
    {
        NSLog(@"Calling Application Bundle ID: %@", sourceApplication);
        NSLog(@"URL scheme:%@", [url scheme]);
        NSLog(@"URL query: %@", [url query]);
        return YES;
    }    
    return NO;
}
```

**Also Add in Delegate**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString*, id> *)options {
//handle here
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:App_Scheme])
    {
        NSLog(@"URL scheme:%@", [url scheme]);
        NSLog(@"URL query: %@", [url query]);
       return YES;
    }
     return FALSE;
}
```

Also add 
**Project - > Target - > Capabilites -> Associated Domains -> Add your domain with**

**App links**: domain here